# Run Safari over ssh (xquartz) from remote linux

Tags: network, safari, ssh, remote-desktop, x11

I have a Mac Mini (2023, M2) and I would like to connect to it and run Safari remotely from a Linux laptop. I am not trying to connect to a Linux (or Windows) server from a Mac client, here the "server" is the Mac Mini, and I am connecting to it remotely. I have tried several things, mainly around trying to get VNC working and, while it works, performance is truly horrible, even just over a fast local network.

It appears that I have X11 installed and forwarding working - if I run `xclock` over `ssh` then it duly appears on my Linux desktop.

However, whenever I try to run something a little more substantial, like `safari` or `chrome`, I get

```
anton@mmini:~$ open -a safari
The application /System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/App/System/Applications/Safari.app cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x60000395ca80 {Error Domain=OSLaunchdErrorDomain Code=125 "Domain does not support specified action" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Domain does not support specified action}}}
```

Is there any way to run `safari` over `X11`/`ssh` or was that just wishful thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS does not use X11, so you can't use ssh -X to run graphical Mac applications remotely. Instead, you can

- use a VNC/Remote Desktop solution to access the whole Mac remotely
- install an X11-based browser (and probably Xquartz) on your Mac and then run that in an ssh/X11 session